# Google apps Script open new window

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Till today everything work good but something went wrong now

i have code in code.gs

```
function demoHtmlServices() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
    html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ff'); 
    html.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
    html.setWidth(700);
    html.setHeight(600);
    ss.show(html);

}
```

ff.html contains

```
<body >
<form class="register active" >
<button  style="font-size:14px;"  id="BackAuctionBut" >Back</button><button  style="font-size:14px;"    >Add</button>           
</form>
</body>
```

So when i press button google open urls in new tab like

> http://5a00f7bc-dcab-4655-9548-d6dc0365e2c5.foo.bar/?
>   http://faa37b59-0545-4bc5-95fe-433d003622cd.foo.bar/?
>   http://78bf0ef1-f8ba-4ac5-92bf-cb7ee6085300.foo.bar/?

Whats is haping with google?
It seems like HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE has disabled by google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be related to this bug - https://plus.google.com/u/0/+EricKoleda/posts/RkSjyezVAGd